# Using OpenMP and OpenMPI together under Slurm

Tags: openmp, slurm, openmpi

I have written a C++ code that uses both OpenMP and OpenMPI. I want to use (let's say) 3 nodes (so size_Of_Cluster should be 3) and use OpenMP in each node to parallelize the for loop (There are 24 cores in a node). In essence I want MPI ranks be assigned to nodes. The Slurm script I have written is as follows. (I have tried many variations but could not come up with the "correct" one. I would be grateful if you could help me.)

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -N 3
#SBATCH -n 72
#SBATCH -p defq
#SBATCH -A akademik
#SBATCH -o %J.out
#SBATCH -e %J.err
#SBATCH --job-name=MIXED

module load slurm
module load shared
module load gcc
module load openmpi

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=24

mpirun -n 3 --bynode ./program
```

Using srun did not help.

Comment: And what is the problem/question?

Comment: On my local Mac with M1Max chip and using just 3 cores (**no** OpenMP), the pure OpenMPI algorithm takes about 30 mins to complete. When I used OpenMP + OpenMPI and run it using the script example in the question, I expected a quicker completion time. But it did not run quicker. In one try (I do not remember the exact script now), it took about 45 mins. So I suspect that the ranks are not distributed among nodes, but I am not sure. In short, **all I desire is to assign ranks to nodes,** and appreciate any help in this reagard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant lines are:

```
#SBATCH -N 3
#SBATCH -n 72

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=24
```

This means you have 72 MPI processes, and each creates 24 thread. For that to be efficient you probably need `24x72` cores. Which you don't have. You should specify:

```
#SBATCH -n 3
```

Then you will have 3 processes, with 24 threads per process.

You don't have to worry about the placement of the ranks on the nodes: that is done by the run time. You could for instance let each process print `MPI_Get_processor_name` to confirm.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer. I tested the script with a simple program, and as you mentioned *MPI_Get_processor_name* function returned the desired output. However when I run my original program it took about 45 mins to complete. So it seems that the problem is not with the script. Maybe I should optimize the OpenMP for loops. Best wishes.